# Intel® Driver & Support Assistant always says there's a newer version available

Tags: windows-10, drivers, intel-core-i7, windows-10-v1809

As of the last few months, something has changed on Intel's site and downloading the latest drivers requires the Intel® Driver & Support Assistant.

Problem is, after installing the latest version from their site, it's telling me to get a new version. Downloading this new version (the exact same EXE as before), I can only uninstall or cancel.

[image]

How can I get Intel's website to recognize I've installed the latest Intel® Driver & Support Assistant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I was being offered the version 3.7.0.6 on the web page you have shared. However, by googling around on the same issue we were suffering, I discovered that Intel had launched version 3.7.0.8 which is the real latest one:

[Intel® Driver & Support Assistant](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28425/Intel-Driver-Support-Assistant)

Comment: That's some black-belt Google-fu right there!